# Как определить размер bitmap картинки?

Tags: android, java, canvas

Как определить размер bitmap картинки, чтобы потом отрисовать ее на экране, не используя ImageView?

Comment: @lenochka727, подобные вопросы вам следует задавать поисковым системам: и время сэкономите, и найдете наверняка.

Answer (score 2):

```
Bitmap.getWidth() - ширина
Bitmap.getHeight() - вышина
```

Comment: Спасибо, но это не работает.

Comment: Не может быть. Приведите код где вы загружаете Bitmap и отдаете в Canvas.

Comment: @lenochka727, нет, это работает. Вы это неправильно используете.